# Infinite series with e and pi

Tags: reference-request, summation

Please, help me to prove that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(\pi n-\sqrt{\pi^2n^2-9})}{n^2}=-\frac{\pi^2}{12 e^3}
$$
I found this fact here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_representations_of_e
but there's no reference.

Comment: Oh, I've also found this fact at the end of this page, but still have no idea, how to prove it. http://gosper.org/bill.html

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128657/gospers-unusual-formula-connecting-e-and-pi

Comment: @BarryCipra Thank you!