# How to calculate the limit of a series in general?

Tags: sequences-and-series

So basically there are a bunch of tests (integral test, ratio test, p-series test, etc) that tells us whether a series converges or not, but none of them gives any information about the limit of a convergent series.

Unless you are lucky and have a convergent geometric series in which case the limit can be found by the formula $\frac{1}{1-r}$.

Or if you are lucky and can somehow formulate the nth partial sum of a series and find the limit as n tends to infinity.

I'm wondering if there is a general method to find the limit of a convergent series?

Comment: There are lots of things you can try (manipulating the series and recognizing a Taylor expansion for example) but there is no general method that always works. In fact that are lots of series that can be shown to convergence but that we don't know which number they converge to; the series that defines catalan's constant for example :)

Comment: In general, it is quite hard, and there is no one-size-fits-all solution.  It is essentially the same problem you have with finding antiderivatives---you can do it numerically, but closed form expressions in terms of elementary functions are rare.

Comment: Plenty of convergent integrals we can't calculate exactly too.

Comment: there are any number of sequence types or progressions a series could be summing up so finding the type would probably be the biggest key attribute needed. examples might include harmonic series, arithmetic series, geometric series, arithmetico-geometric series, and random combinations etc.

Comment: Finding sum of a series is far more complicated than establishing that the sum exists. In fact if you have found a sum of new series then it is sufficient ground to make a mathematical paper out of it.  See one such example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1128657/72031

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no general method, and when it is possible, it can be very hard.

A good example is the *Riemann zeta series*:
$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{n^s},$$
which converges for $\mathrm{Re\,(s)>1}$.

For $s$ even integer, its limits have been known since *Euler*, for instance
$$\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}6,\quad\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90},\; \&c. $$
However, its values for odd integers are not known (except for numerical approximations), and it was only  in 1979 that Roger Apéry proved $\zeta(3)$ is irrational; in 2000, Tanguy Rivoal proved an infinity of $\zeta(s)$ (s odd integer) are irrational, and it is only conjectured they're all irrational.

Answer (score 2):

General? No, but I can provide some tips.

First, try to see if you can construct a telescoping series out of it.

> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}=1$$

Second, try to recognize it.

> $$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\\\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\\\ln(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}kx^k\\\vdots$$

Third, try to turn it into something you recognize, either by differentiating, integrating, factoring, separating, etc.

> $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^k=x\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^{k-1}=x\frac d{dx}\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=x\frac d{dx}\frac1{1-x}=\frac x{(1-x)^2}$$

But not all series come with a known closed form, and not all that do come with such look pretty. For example, the odd values of the p-series are unknown when they converge, but the even values are known, but far more complicated than their integral counterparts:

> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6\\\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$$

As well as some others,

> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k-\frac1{k+\frac rm}=-\ln(2m)-{\frac {\pi }{2}}\cot \left({\frac {r\pi }{m}}\right)+2\sum _{n=1}^{\left\lfloor {\frac {m-1}{2}}\right\rfloor }\cos \left({\frac {2\pi nr}{m}}\right)\ln \sin \left({\frac {\pi n}{m}}\right)$$

You just really can't tell without experience IMHO.

Comment: I haven't seen that last sum before. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen [Gauss' digamma theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss.27s_digamma_theorem)